# Can you merge two sqlite databases on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, database, sqlite, multiple-databases

Well the question says it all. Is there an easy way to merge two sqlite databases on the iPhone? Their structure is identical and the primary key is guaranteed to be unique across the two databases.

I know you can do a INSERT INTO SELECT, but I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution.

Comment: Is there something inelegant about `INSERT INTO SELECT ...`? Merging databases is extremely scenario-specific, so I'd be surprised (albeit pleasantly so), if a general tool was available.

Comment: Not really, I am implementing it currently. Was just wondering if there was a "command-line style" way :)

Comment: The "command line style" way is just going to do the same thing; there is no magic concatenation functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. The INSERT INTO SELECT is working great :)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked it thoroughly, but maybe you'll find something in: [Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Introduction/Introduction.html). It's included in the Xcode documentation, so you probably already have it.

**EDIT: I'm just offering a starting point, not a verified solution.**